# Drop / collapse rows

Tags: r

Say I have a dataset like the one below:

```
x y z
1 9 3
3 0 3
4 0 2
1 4 1
5 1 9
4 2 3
9 0 1
```

I would like to to drop / collapse all the rows that are repeated based on the value in column z so that my new data set would read like this:

```
x y z
1 9 3
4 0 2
1 4 1
5 1 9
```

Rows 2 and 6 have been dropped because they contained a repeated value in z (the value of 3) I would simply like R to drop all remaining iterations of that whole row.

Answer (score 2):

If your data is stored in data frame `df`, you could do something like:

`df <- df[!duplicated(df$z), ]`